# CentOS - using PXE to install it on my host ( kickstart configuration )

Tags: linux, bash, centos, pxe, kickstart

I am trying to install an OS from our server through PXE ( Preboot Execution Environment ).

However, on my host, I have two disks say A ( /dev/sda ) and B ( /dev/sdb )

The default installation path goes to disk A while I expect to install it on disk B. ( No selection appears )

Should I edit the kickstart file or there are some other configuration files I should modify ?

1. Can I write a bash to let my kickstart file to choose which disk to install ?
2. The other way is to give a fixed path and then just install the OS on that disk.

Please give your advice.